# Identify EAN / UPC barcode numbers from image in PHP / JS?

Tags: php, javascript, image-processing, barcode

I'm looking for a way to identify EAN / UPC (primarily EAN) barcode numerals from a camera-captured image in PHP or Javascript. I've found a few libraries for Java  but ideally would like one of PHP or JS to manage it. Not sure if feasible, but any advice appreciated!

Edit: tried http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx with some sample images from iPod Touch camera, with mixed success.

Comment: There is probably going to be a server-side tool for this. Can you install / use command-line tools? What system are you on?

Comment: At the moment on Unix/Apache VPS, but just wondering how feasible it is on any platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a project where this was a requirement so we ended up using this library. http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/

A fellow consultant working with me wrote up an image crop tool that allowed a user to crop an uploaded image down to just the barcode, this was then shoved into a ghetto MQ using sqlite, where a resident agent running on the machine polled sqlite and processing pending records ( transaction_id, path2file, date of trx ) reported back to the application via a web service call the result.

I was the one that did the R&D for this feature request and I don't remember any bar scanning libraries for PHP plus Python isn't so painful to learn, just got to master daemonizing a python script to run as a service then read up on urllib2 for sending the response back to the PHP app.  We did it in 48 man hours between two people, add another 15-20 hours to learn enough about Python and it should be doable.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive reply. I have a little Python experience, so this could be workable. Did you use any particular libraries for image cropping, and what kind of intervals did you poll the SQLite DB?

Comment: If you mean libraries for browsers, I think he just wrote up some quick one off deal.  For back end, Python has PIL and PHP has GD.

Comment: Right, I think I'll give this a shot - haven't found anything at all specific to PHP/JS, but this sounds like it could be viable. Thanks again.

Comment: Let me know via comments if I can give you any other pointers, until I found zbar I was thinking my partner and I were dead in the water for the inventory system we developed for a client.

Answer (score 6):

http://tobeytailor.s3.amazonaws.com/get_barcode_from_image/index.html

Comment: this was already marked as answered, but others should check this out.

Comment: View the page source.  It is all client side JavaScript.  This posts links the project and one similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869445/reading-barcode-from-an-image-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I think u could use some api to help you in your project.
the checked answer has some limits in the program language and update data.

We have several different types of EAN code.
We can call them Gtin code.
It could be 8, 12, 13 or 14 digits long.

You could use this database:
https://market.mashape.com/mignify/gtin2product

It's a very user friendly and intelligent API, U can use it to get directly the product information by gtin. Also It could help u to extract the information of a page from E-commerce site.

Hope could help U.