# reading barcode from an image using javascript

Tags: javascript, image, barcode

I need a javascript code that will read/ extract barcode from an image. 
for example, the image may be embedded in a web page and i wan to pass the image to the Javascript function.

The function should read/parse the image and extract the barcode from the image.

Answer (score 20):

There is [QuaggaJS](https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/) library (open source) for reading barcodes, all done in JavaScript.

It currently supports EAN, CODE 128, CODE 39, EAN 8, UPC-A, UPC-C, and CODABAR

I suspect it will meet your needs.

### Update: 2021-August

Looks like the original QuaggaJS is no longer actively maintained.

[Quagga2](https://github.com/ericblade/quagga2) is active and continues the goals of the original.

(thanks @bertasoft for the tip!)

Comment: You meant 'I expect...'?

Comment: Maybe 'I hope' :) Depends on the specific needs of the original poster.

Comment: QuaggaJS is a dead project, goto the fork https://github.com/ericblade/quagga2