# Read barcode with smartphone and enter value in text input

Tags: php, jquery, barcode

I´m looking for a way to read barcodes with my smarthpone.
The code value should be entered in a text input so i can save it with php to my database.
Are you familior with a script like this?

I´d like it to be a web application like a html/php/jquery document
that trigger the camera to read the br code and then put the result in a text input.

Is this possible?

Comment: Nope, it will have to be an installed app - a web app does not have access to the users camera or filesystem, for (good) security reasons. You could just have a fileupload form field, then handle the image processing serverside though

Comment: If you do go with the image upload route, the following would be a good start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869445/reading-barcode-from-an-image-using-javascript

Comment: Thank you steve. I will take a look at this. But i think it will be to slow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to download "Softkeys Barcode keyboard".
It´s a very nice app that uses the campera to scan and type the info just where you like it.

Here is a link to it.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tecit.android.barcodekbd.full

There is also a demo version availible for free.